# Python - Finding integer solutions to a^3+b^3=c^3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume c is given. Find up to 2 unique solutions a, b such that  a^3+b^3=c^3.

My solution:

```
c=int(input("Choose c", ))
k=(c-1)**(1/3)
counter=0
a=1
while a<k:
    a+=1
    b=int((c-a**3)**(1/3))
    if a**3+b**3==c and a>b:
        counter+=1
        print(a,b)
    if counter==2:
        break
        print(a,b)
```

Explanation:

1: First we choose an integer c.

2: k is the upper limit a.

3: I want a counter so that I can get 2 different solutions.

4: a should begin from 1.

5: This is to test every integer from 1 to k.

6: a should increase with 1 when the "if" isn't satisfied.

7: Defining b.

8: This is the equation we want solved.

9: So if the equation is solved then we add 1 to the counter.

10: We also print a and b.

11-13: This is to make sure we stop when we get the second solution.

**PROBLEM!** If I put in c=1729 it only returns (12,1). Why won't it continue to search for more solutions?

Comment: Is your question about `a^3+b^3=c^3` or `a^3+b^3=c`? Because if the first case, you'll have a hard time finding any solution...

Comment: Why not use `Newton Raphson` for root finding. Unlike your method, it converges, exponentially, and to exclude already determined roots, you need to use [polynomial deflation](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/poly_2.htm)

Comment: "Why won't it continue to search for more solutions?" It _did_ continue, but didn't find any. That's the only solution.

Comment: @Kevin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks for the link. That would have been really useful information for the OP to include in his post... >_>

Comment: @Holt Sorry it is c^3.

Comment: @Lozansky Your code however solves for `c` and not `c**3`. In the latter case no solutions exist.

Comment: @Christoph Oh I meant c... Thought I had c cubed in my code.

Comment: @Lozansky Then why not edit your question to reflect what you are actually asking for? You've let it stand as if you are asking for solutions of an equation which is known to have no solutions (by Fermat's Last Theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other solution is (9,10). The problem is that your expression for the computation of `b`:

```
b=int((c-a**3)**(1/3))
```

Has rounding issues. Try computing `(1729-9**3)**(1/3.)` in Python and you'll get `9.999999999999998`. `int` of that is `9` instead of `10`. A quick fix for this issue is to offset the computation by very small number, e.g.

```
b=int((c-a**3)**(1/3)+1.e-10)
```

In response to the comment: Also, your last `if` statement needs to have the `print` line before the `break`.

Comment: Or use the round() function, as in: int(round((c-a**3)**(1/3)))

Comment: Thanks. But now I only get the solution (10,9). Is my counter not correctly placed? I don't understand why the loop doesn't continue after the programs find the first solution.

Comment: @Lozansky you should swap `break` and `print`

Comment: @Christoph Oh thanks. Think this will be my last issue. I get (10,9) and then (12,1), (12,1). Why do I get (12,1) two times?

Comment: Well, maybe just remove the last `print` statement completely since you already print when you get the match.

Comment: @Christoph Ah thank you very much for the help. Now it works.

Comment: @Lozansky: No problem. Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem.